# Java JFrame setting custom opacity

Tags: java, jframe

How do I change the opacity of a jframe from user input, lets say from a spinner?

```
int opacity = 7;
double dOpacity = opacity/10;
String sOpacity = Double.toString(dOpacity)+"f";
this.setOpacity(sOpacity); //???
```

The above code produces a bunch of errors. Is there anyway to get a opacity number, lets say 6, and then convert it to a value that 'this.setOpacity(sOpacity);' will accept?

errors :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: GuiClock.Main.setOpacity
    at GuiClock.Main.cinitComponents(Main.java:97)
    at GuiClock.Main.<init>(Main.java:16)
    at GuiClock.Main$6.run(Main.java:168)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @MadProgrammer posted the errors, but I think its more a syntax problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your code : `dOpacity= 0.0`

```
    int opacity = 7;
    float dOpacity = (float)opacity/10; //casting to float , here dOpacity=0.7
    String sOpacity = Float.toString(dOpacity)+"f"; // sOpacity="0.7f"
    this.setOpacity(Float.parseFloat(sOpacity)); //setOpacity(0.7f);
```

Comment: Not sure why you need to convert the `float` to a `String` rather then using the `dOpacity` value directly...but that's just me...

Answer (score 1):

The [setOpacity](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setOpacity%28float%29) method uses a `float` as parameter. You're passing a `String`.

Try `this.setOpacity(Float.parseFloat(sOpacity));`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, no errors are produced, however the jframe's opacity is 0 even though input should show otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting a String as parameter to the setOpacity method, which only takes doubles.

Comment: I tried using doubles, however still it only will accept something in the form of : 0.7f

Comment: 0.7f is not a string it means 0.7 float. Try float fOpacity = (float)opacity/10;
You could also say for example: double dOpacity = 0.7f;
because a double is just actually a larger float.